# How to monitor communication between two Erlang nodes

Tags: erlang, communication

I'm playing around with distributed Erlang. 
It's a great fun, but I want to reveal the magic a bit and see what is actually being sent between Erlang nodes.

Could you please suggest any Erlang modules or external tools available for this?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

BTW, Debian users can install Wireshark using `sudo apt-get install wireshark`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a network sniffer, like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) sniffing on 4369/tcp? Wireshark has a special filter for the erlang distributed protocol (see ERLDP in the list of built-in expressions).

For more low-level information about the protocol itself, see http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_dist_protocol.html

Here's a capture sample, between a linux node and windows node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about it. Also I've found out that `epmd -d -d` can provide some info.